# C# - Parsing JSON to multiple objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to create multiple objects out of a JSON result.
My JSON looks like that:

**EDIT**

```
[{"quality":"hd","type":"video/mp4","width":1920,"height":1080,"link":"http://player.vimeo.com/external/255898412.hd.mp4?s=8766561d230749d75a0ddde2ddfbeb69e0e5198e&profile_id=175&oauth2_token_id=1040381751","created_time":"2018-02-15T15:46:25+02:00","fps":23.98,"size":3113207678,"md5":"b6beed65b699df870e481045178accc5","link_secure":"https://player.vimeo.com/external/255898412.hd.mp4?s=8766561d230749d75a0ddde2ddfbeb69e0e5198e&profile_id=175&oauth2_token_id=1040381751"},{"quality":"sd","type":"video/mp4","width":640,"height":360,"link":"http://player.vimeo.com/external/255898412.sd.mp4?s=b51b55f6bd6e1af2a8f48571e5804d91e6a82533&profile_id=164&oauth2_token_id=1040381751","created_time":"2018-02-15T15:46:05+02:00","fps":23.98,"size":536864946,"md5":"af227a5526af15d2bce6ac951d6cf06b","link_secure":"https://player.vimeo.com/external/255898412.sd.mp4?s=b51b55f6bd6e1af2a8f48571e5804d91e6a82533&profile_id=164&oauth2_token_id=1040381751"},{"quality":"sd","type":"video/mp4","width":960,"height":540,"link":"http://player.vimeo.com/external/255898412.sd.mp4?s=b51b55f6bd6e1af2a8f48571e5804d91e6a82533&profile_id=165&oauth2_token_id=1040381751","created_time":"2018-02-15T15:46:05+02:00","fps":23.98,"size":1242328160,"md5":"1963f908509b14fd7a40dc46bfa6c519","link_secure":"https://player.vimeo.com/external/255898412.sd.mp4?s=b51b55f6bd6e1af2a8f48571e5804d91e6a82533&profile_id=165&oauth2_token_id=1040381751"},{"quality":"hd","type":"video/mp4","width":1280,"height":720,"link":"http://player.vimeo.com/external/255898412.hd.mp4?s=8766561d230749d75a0ddde2ddfbeb69e0e5198e&profile_id=174&oauth2_token_id=1040381751","created_time":"2018-02-15T15:46:05+02:00","fps":23.98,"size":1977386604,"md5":"af38f067bd39f4f5bb71bad72f925337","link_secure":"https://player.vimeo.com/external/255898412.hd.mp4?s=8766561d230749d75a0ddde2ddfbeb69e0e5198e&profile_id=174&oauth2_token_id=1040381751"},{"quality":"hls","type":"video/mp4","link":"https://player.vimeo.com/external/255898412.m3u8?s=f25b7114977a0c6b37739886da189051ed31999e&oauth2_token_id=1040381751","created_time":"2018-02-15T15:46:25+02:00","fps":23.98,"size":3113207678,"md5":"b6beed65b699df870e481045178accc5","link_secure":"https://player.vimeo.com/external/255898412.m3u8?s=f25b7114977a0c6b37739886da189051ed31999e&oauth2_token_id=1040381751"}]
```

it should be parsed into 3 objects.
I got a `VideoFileModel.cs` class that looks like that:

```
public partial class VideoFileModel
{
    [JsonProperty("quality")]
    public string Quality { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("width")]
    public long? Width { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("height")]
    public long? Height { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("link")]
    public string Link { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("created_time")]
    public System.DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("fps")]
    public double Fps { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("size")]
    public long Size { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("md5")]
    public string Md5 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("link_secure")]
    public string LinkSecure { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm trying to do at the moment, is parsing it like that:

```
string json = Helpers.HTTPFetch(url, method, headers, body, contentType);
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VideoFileModel>(json);
```

but I'm pretty sure it's not working, or at least not in the way I want it to work.
what should I change?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You should try :

` var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<VideoFileModel>>(json);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply use `List<>` when deserializing :

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<VideoFileModel>>(json);
```

There are is a list of `VideoFileModel` in your JSON that you trying to deserialize into a single object.

Following gets deserialized:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

As per OP updated JSON. It still gets deserialized:

[image]

Comment: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[VimeoCore.VideoFileModel]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or ....

Comment: change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.

Comment: (And i cannot change the json result)

Comment: It is working fine for me, I have added a screenshot as well.

Comment: @AaYy If you are still getting that error, then the JSON you posted above is not what you are trying to parse.

Comment: I'm sorry, i passed an edited json answer through some website. i edited it

Comment: @AaYy I have tried new JSON as well and it works fine too.